# .NET Framework 4.8 Web Site not loading .NET Standard 2.0 lib EFCore 3.1 dependencies through (Microsoft.Data.SqlClient / SqlClient.SNI related...)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ef-core-3.1, .net-standard-2.0, .net-4.8

Got a .NET Framework 4.8 Web Site (that's the key here, not a Web App...) and I've referenced a .NET Standard 2.0 class library in that internally uses EFCore 3.1. I can't get things to work at runtime, I get get as far as making it semi-happy to compile by installing several of the same NuGet packages in the Web Site as well (which I don't like, why won't the dependencies automatically end up in the bin dir from the .NET Standard lib..?)

I always end up at issues with SqlClient of some sort, whether it's 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform' or eventually getting an error of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.x64.dll missing from the bin dir... I've tried locating Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.x64.dll manually to copy it that way but can't find it anywhere...

I'm at a loss here, I've combed through the web, gone through multiple posts here and every one I've found seems to have a fix whereby you can put some script into the csproj/vbproj file and that'll work around it, but the key here is this is a Web Site without a project file, only the sln file for the solution (or web.config)...

Can anyone offer any help or advice with where to go with this? (Please don't say convert to web app, that's not feasible at the moment...)

Comment: Do you update your executing project with this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/platforms#net-framework ?